# Why is it sometimes kJ only, and in other times kJ/mol? What's the difference?

Tags: enthalpy

Here is an example in my book.  Computing the enthalpy of formation $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{f}$ *via* multiple enthalpies of reaction $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r}$ I notice some of the equations run by $\pu{kJ/mol}$ and others by $\pu{kJ}$ only.  I'm puzzled about the conceptual difference between these values.  How do they relate to each other?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Your own reasoning – based on searching, reading and thinking – is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own explicit  effort.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Asking should be rather the last than the first idea coming to your mind. // Using photos/screenshots of text ) instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused nor referred in answers.

Comment: If you understand difference between $\pu{g}$ and $\pu{g/mol}$, you understand difference between $\pu{kJ}$ and $\pu{kJ/mol}$. // Another thing is, if the units are correctly used. We cannot explain why they were eventually used incorrectly. Always compare what you know with what you read, do not take the latter automatically as right.

Comment: The book(s) are being sloppy and you are right to be confused. For a given reaction the heat is computed for the reaction as written, that is, for the molar amounts specified in the reaction equation. Sometimes reactions are written on a per mole basis, with the extent of reaction expressed as a molar amount. Heats of formation are typically defined as molar quantities, defined on a per-mole basis, for instance  kJ/mol. The short of it is that people (myself included) are sometimes sloppy, and designation as a molar quantity and use of appropriate units is sometimes neglected.

Comment: In the bottom example, for instance, the heat of formation of carbon disulfide should be declared in $\pu{kJ/mol}$ units. And yes, in the case of reaction (5) in one case it is given in per-mole units but not in another. That's sloppy.

Answer (score 3):

The keyword is [dimension analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

For instance, in example 1-7, the aim is to determine the *standard* enthalpy of formation $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{f}$ for $\ce{SO2}$ (note the subscript is `f`) determined with equations 1, 2, and 3.  After rearrangement $3 \rightarrow 4$ you add the equations to obtain equation #5 which however describes the enthalpy of *reaction* (note subscript is `r`) to yield $\pu{2 mol}$  of $\ce{SO2}$ instead of the conventionally tabulated enthalpy of *formation* (again subscript `f`) for $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{SO2}$.

Thus, $$\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r} = \pu{2 mol} \times \Delta{}H_\mathrm{f} = \pu{2 mol} \times(\pu{-296 kJ/mol}) = \pu{-592 kJ}.$$ One may argue the publisher was sloppy when writing `2` instead of `2 mol` in this line.

You may retain that $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r}$ as a special case (mathematically speaking, a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)) of the more general $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r}$.  That is to say, for a reaction yielding $\pu{4.2 mol}$ of $\ce{SO2}$, the reaction enthalpy $\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r}$ is:

$$\Delta{}H_\mathrm{r} = \pu{4.2 mol} \times \Delta{}H_\mathrm{f} = \pu{4.2 mol} \times(\pu{-296 kJ/mol}) = \pu{-1243.2 kJ.}$$